# DML statement returning distinct values (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to execute a delete statement which will return me 2 rows. Then I want to return the distinct values of some columns. In my case I am certain that using distinct will return me a single row. But Oracle does not allow me to use distinct in RETURNING statement. Is there any elegant way to achieve this? Basically I want to avoid using collections and loops in my case.

e.g.

```
DECLARE

  TYPE t_object_id_tab IS TABLE OF bulk_collect_test.object_id%TYPE;

  l_tab  t_object_id_tab;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM bulk_collect_test
  RETURNING object_id BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(‘Deleted IDs : ' || l_tab.count || ' rows');

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

I want to be replaced by something of the equivalent of:

```
DECLARE
  l_obj_id bulk_collect_test.object_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM bulk_collect_test
  RETURNING distinct object_id INTO l_obj_id; --assuming distinct object_id will always give me 1 row

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Comment: Returning only dealt with single value. While you are trying to handle multiple values with it.

Comment: You cannot return multiple values (from an update that affects > 1 row) without using BULK COLLECT - and collections.

You are right, there is no distinct clause. So you will then need to iterate through the collection and pull out your distinct set. Hard to give you the code for that without knowing the table and columns, but I can tell you that a string-indexed collection can make for very clean distinct-ifying of your data. :-)

And it will be very fast.

Comment: @StevenFeuerstein thanks for your reply. I can write the code for using collections and iterating through them. I just wanted to know if there was anyway to avoid it and get it done in a single statement. I haven't found any option online for it, so I'll stick to using collections. :-)